# Phonegap "Error calling method on NPObject" while uploading the image from android device

Tags: android, file-upload, cordova

I am new to phonegap and i am having the issue when uploading the image from android device, the I think the **window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI** function throws an **Error calling method on NPObject** error, my complete code is as below. Please have a look and share your ideas.

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function (imageURI) {
 var _this = this;
 var encodedURL = encodeURI("http://api.xyz.com/DataService/DataService.svc/UploadImage");
 try {
     this.op = new FileUploadOptions();
     this.op.fileKey = "file";
     this.op.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
     this.op.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
     this.op.chunkedMode = false;
     this.op.headers = { Connection: "close" };

     this.ft = new FileTransfer();
     if (window.device != undefined && device.platform == "Android") {
         window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, function (fileEntry) {
             fileEntry.file(function (fileObj) {
                 var fileFullPath = fileObj.fullPath;
                 _this.op.fileName = fileFullPath.substr(fileFullPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                 _this.ft.upload(fileFullPath, encodedURL, function (data) { alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data)); }, function (data) { alert("Failour: " + JSON.stringify(data)); }, _this.op, true);
             });
         });
     } else {
            this.ft.upload(imageURI, encodedURL, function (data) { alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify(data)); }, function (data) { alert("Failour: " + JSON.stringify(data)); }, this.op, true);
       }
 } catch (_error) {
     alert(_error);
     }
},
function (message) { },
{
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
});
}
```